# Finding the inverse of the function $f(x) = \frac{5}{2}-x, \text{if $x<2$}, \frac{1}{x}, \text{if $x\ge2$}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

My question regards finding the inverse of the following function:  $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{5}{2}-x,  & \text{if $x<2$} \\
\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if $x\ge2$}
\end{cases}.$$

As far as my attempts have gone, I have separated this piecewise function into its individual pieces.

For the first piece, I have found the inverse in the following manner. I found the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{5}{2}-x$, which ends up as $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{5}{2}-x$. Then, for the new domain of this piece, $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{5}{2}-x < 2$, which yields $x > \frac{1}{2}$.

For the second piece, I have found the inverse in the following manner. I found the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, which ends up as $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then, for the new domain of this piece, $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{x}\ge2$, which yields $x\le\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus, my final piecewise function would be $$f^{-1}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{5}{2}-x,  & \text{if $x > \frac{1}{2}$} \\
\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if $x\le\frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}.$$

However, according to my teacher, the domain of the second piece ($\frac{1}{x}$) is instead $0<x\le\frac{1}{2}$. **Why exactly must $x$ be greater than $0$?** I have absolutely no idea where I either went wrong in my arithmetic or overlooked some fundamental concept in ascertaining the inverse function. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you think $f^{-1}(0)$ might be?

Comment: @Henry, I see what you are saying, but what would be the issue with finding $f^{-1}(-1)$? Why must $x$ be greater than $0$?

Comment: I think your teacher's point is either (a) $0 \lt \frac1x \le \frac12$ when $x \gt 2$ or (b) no matter how you define $f^{-1}(x)$ for $x \le 0$ you will not have $f\left(f^{-1}(x)\right) = x$ for $x \le 0$

Comment: @Henry, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In the image below, you'll see a graph of the function $f(x)$ that you've defined in your question. What is the domain of $f(x)$, and what is its range? In particular, notice that $f(x)$ does *not* cross the $x$ axis. Therefore, its inverse cannot take $x$ values less than zero.

Another way of saying this is: if $f(x)$ cannot take negative $y$ values, then $f^{-1}(x)$ cannot take negative $x$ values. For example, think about how $f(x) = x^2$ does not take negative $y$ values, and how $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x}$ does not take negative $x$ values.

[image: Plot of the piecewise function defined in the question]

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you know; a function means you give me some something, I give you another one thing. In our scalar function case, we write $f: x \mapsto y$. The inverse function of this specific one to one function means that if you give me $y$ I want the $x$ which we had before. We can think of it as another function  ; some other way of mapping, $g=f^{-1} : x \mapsto y$.

The problem with $f^{-1}(x)$ with $x \leq 0$ is that there is no $y \leq 0$ on the graph of our function $f$. We say that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not surjective. In fact the range our function is $y \in (0,\infty)$ as $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=\infty$ and our function is strictly decreasing but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$.  You give me any negative $y$, I can't give you the $x$ that when I substitute it in the formula I get $y$. To keep this problem from happening we've got to restrict $x$ in $f^{-1}$ to $x \in (0,\infty)$ as $f :  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{+} $ is surjective.